# Discrete Valuation Property

Tags: ring-theory, valuation-theory

If $\nu$ is the discrete valuation on a field $K$, what would $\nu(x-y)$ satisfy for $x,y\in K$? Can I say that $\nu(x-y)=\nu(x+(-y))\geq \min(\nu(x),\nu(-y))=\min(\nu(x),\nu(y))$?

Comment: the idea is right, but how do you know $\nu(-y) = \nu(y)$?

Comment: @gt6989b I got it now. :)